# Can't click on a element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Code that i am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

wd = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.dailyfx.com/economic-calendar#next-seven-days'
wd.get(url)
time.sleep(20)
try:
  wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]/div/div/button/img").click()
except:
  print('No Calendar Advertisement')
try:
  wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/button").click()
except:
  print('No Cookies Button')
time.sleep(3)
try:
  wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span").click()
except:
  print('No App Advertisement')
#Clear calendar filter
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]").click()
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/label").click()
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/label").click()
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/label").click()
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/label").click()
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/label").click()
#Selecting only United States
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span").click()
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/label").click()
#Closing Calendar Filter
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]").click()
#Working part:
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[5]/table/tbody/tr[13]/td[1]/div/div[1]").click()
```

https://www.dailyfx.com/economic-calendar#next-seven-days

So, I am accessing this website and trying to click on a element. As you can see, the website shows some economic news and when you click on it, it shows a graphic with information, which is my goal - opening the graph. For some reason,  I can only open the graphic when the table data (`td\[1\]`) is 1(that occurs just for the first economic news). When the table data(`td\[3\]`) change to 3(economic news that are more distant to happen), I can't open the graphic anymore.  This code works:

```
wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div\[5\]/div/div\[4\]/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[1\]/div/div/div\[4\]/div\[5\]/table/tbody/tr\[13\]/td\[1\]/div/div\[1\]").click()  When change to td\[3\], doesnt work: wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div\[5\]/div/div\[4\]/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[1\]/div/div/div\[4\]/div\[5\]/table/tbody/tr\[93\]/td\[3\]/div/div\[1\]").click()
```

I tried clicking on multiple different elements, but still doesn't work when trying to click on `td\[3\]` elements.

Tried to open a graphic of a economic news but only work when `td\[1\]`, not for `td\[3\`].

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck?

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, the regular error of cant find element by XPATH.

Comment: When a change the td[1] for td[3], to open the graph it cant find the element to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (find element, scroll to it, sleep, click), works for me

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr[13]/td[3]")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', element)
time.sleep(1)
element.click()
```

If you are still having problems try these alternatives to `element.click()`

```
# alternative 1
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)

# alternative 2
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
actions = ActionChains(driver)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# alternative 3
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.click(element).perform()

# alternative 4
actions.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

# alternative 5
actions.move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()

# alternative 6
actions.click_and_hold(element).perform()
time.sleep(1)
actions.release(element).perform()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to solve this problem for a couple of days. Again, thank you!!!!

Comment: @FHAlex You are welcome! Do you use the first code or one of the alternatives?

Comment: I used the first code